# How to render to two QWidget of one QMainWindow with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qwidget, hwnd

Having two widgets in one window with QT 5.13, one widget should render preview, while the other one should render with another camera. We used EGL. Should I create one OpenGL context attached to each QWidget/HWND used in main thread and render to two HWND, or two sub thread each take charge of each context? We need the OpenGL resource(shader/texture) shared.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @JerikcXIONG Yeah. Need to create a thread per widget. Just get two HWND in two separate widget, and create two separate OpenGL context using EGL in two thread. All EGL & OpenGL related operation must be in the widget's thread.

Comment: Cool. Do you have any sample code ? @heLomaN

Comment: @JerikcXIONG Here is a blog about using EGL with HWND. https://www.saschawillems.de/blog/2015/04/19/using-opengl-es-on-windows-desktops-via-egl/ Sorry for no demo code to be public, but just create a std::thread and do sth in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [link](https://community.khronos.org/t/drawing-two-rendering-context-in-same-time/714) there is a discussion on EGL and the opengl context. I have not experience about
egl programming but in qt desktop application it's possible share the same context on two different view and on one view use a different camera.